# Why is $f(z)$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

Given a finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ we can define the function:
$$f(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{d\mu(x)}{x-z}.$$
I need to show that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^{+} =\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0\}$, but I don't know how to finish the argument. I was trying to use [Morera's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) together with Fubini's Theorem to prove:
$$\int_{\mathbb{C}^{+}} f(z)dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{C}^{+}}\frac{dz}{x-z}d\mu(x) = 0$$
but I can't convince myself that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{C}^{+}}\frac{dz}{x-z} = 0.$$
Is there any reason for this integral to be zero? Maybe expand $(x-z)^{-1}$ in power series of $z$ or something like this?

Comment: When applying Morera's theorem, you have to integrate on curves not on the domain. Then for any fixed real $x$, $z \mapsto \frac{1}{x-z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^+$.

Comment: You need to show that on $\mathbb{C}^+$, if $C$ is any closed contour, then $\oint_C f(z)\,dz=0$.

Comment: The easiest is to show that the complex derivative exists using the dominated convergence theorem (and of course this shows that the derivative is what should be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $z\in\mathbb{C}^+$. Consider the map

$$g:h\mapsto\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu(x)}{x-(z+h)}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu(x)}{x-z}}{h}$$

for $h$ in some neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, we choose a neighborhood small enough so that $z+h\in\mathbb{C}^+$. If we can show that $\lim_{h\to0}g(h)$ exists, then we are done. Now it is easy to check that

$$g(h)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu(x)}{(x-z-h)(x-z)}.$$

It's now easy to see that $x\mapsto \frac{1}{(x-z-h)(x-z)}$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, as $z,z+h\in\mathbb{C}^+$, and that we can find such a bound independent of $h$. Thus $\left\lvert \frac{1}{(x-z-h)(x-z)}\right\rvert$ is dominated by some constant function, which is clearly integrable as $\mu$ is finite. Choosing any sequence $\{h_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ in the domain of $f$ with limit $0$, we then have that

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}g(h_j)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu(x)}{(x-z-h_j)(x-z)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu(x)}{(x-z)^2}$$

by the dominated convergence theorem. As the sequence was arbitrary, the limit exists and equals the above (which is also the derivative of your function at $z$).

So as $z\in\mathbb{C}^+$ was arbitrary, the function is complex differentiable on all of $\mathbb{C}^+$, i.e. it's holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^+$.